# Load my Custom Google API from Javascript Library (remote projects)

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to load my custom Google Api (Appengine Endpoints) to my frontend project but I receive `TypeError: gapi.client.myCustomApi is undefined`.

I have **two projects** in Appengine (Frontend and backend project). I have generated the **Api Key** from the **Backend Project**. So, I'm following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_js

This is my **index.html** in code in Frontend project:

```
<script>
function loadGapi(){
gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyBvg9bSWGUHhAO-TPIww3KuKhJqC2_BAFk');
gapi.client.load('myCustomApi', 'v1', function() {
    gapi.client.myCustomApi.list().execute(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    });
}, 'https://my-backend-project.appspot.com/_ah/api');
}
 </script>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=loadGapi"> </script>
```

Please reply if anyone can help me. Thanks!

**EDIT1:**

I have used **gapi.client.request** for testing, and it works perfect.  gapi.client.load doesn't work yet.

```
gapi.client.request({
   "path": "/myCustomApi/v1.0/list",
   "root": "https://my-backend-project.appspot.com/_ah/api"
}).execute(function (response) { 
console.log(response); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it! Was my mistake. Just to need to put "v1.0" in version field. So, for example:

```
<script>
function loadGapi(){
gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyBvg9bSWGUHhAO-TPIww3KuKhJqC2_BAFk');
gapi.client.load('myCustomApi', 'v1.0', function() {
    gapi.client.myCustomApi.list().execute(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    });
  }, 'https://my-backend-project.appspot.com/_ah/api');
}
</script>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=loadGapi"> </script>
```